# How to toggle a radio button in Typescript React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, radio-button

I know this is a rookie question, but I'm stuck and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a Typescript file (.tsx) and four answer choices. The user can only pick one. However, when the user clicks more than one radio button, you guessed it, the previously selected buttons stay selected.

I've seen examples where others use:

```
<input type="radio" 
    value="option1" 
    checked={this.state.selectedOption === 'option1'} 
    onChange={this.handleOptionChange} />
```

This may work for some, but in my .tsx file, I can't use `this.state`. Every reference I find is using this scenario.

I tried using this in my `handleInputChange` function, but all the radio buttons became selected.
`e.target.value === e.target.name ? setChecked(true) : setChecked(false)`

Here's what I have and thanks in advance for any advice.

```
// Quiz.tsx

import React, { useState } from "react"

interface Props {
  questionnaire: any
}

const Quiz = (props: Props) => {

// setting checked state to false by default
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
    // if the current value equals the current input name, mark checked as true
    // However this makes all radio buttons checked as true (all selected)
    e.target.value === e.target.name ? setChecked(true) : setChecked(false)
  }




{props.questionnaire.questions[currentQuestion].answers.map(
   ({ title, score }: any) => (
      <>
        <label>
           <div>
              <input
                 type="radio"
                 value={score}
                 name={score}
                 onChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
                 checked={checked}
               />
                 {title}
           </div>
        </label>
      </>
    )
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:
(I'm using `any` only because I don't know your `questionnaire` types, but you should consider adding the right types)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  questionnaire: any;
}

const Quiz = (props: Props) => {
  const [checkBox, setCheckBox] = useState();

  const handleInputChange = (score: any) => {
    setCheckBox(score);
  };

  return (
    // <-- Here you need to return something from component
    <>
     {
       props.questionnaire.questions[currentQuestion].answers.map((
      {title, score}: any) => (
        <label>
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={score}
              name={score}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(score)}
              checked={score === checkBox}
            />
            {title}
          </div>
        </label>
      )
    }
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for getting me over this hump!

Comment: why any type? 

Comment: @DoubleM I've told the reason in my answer , (I'm using `any` only because I don't know your `questionnaire` types, but you should consider adding the right types)